# Laravel share Auth::User() info

Tags: laravel-5

I made a `BaseController` to share user information but that doesn't work.   `Auth::user()->id` and `Auth::user()->email` are empty.

How can I archive this? Whats the best approach?

```
class BaseAdminController extends Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->initMenu();
    }

    private function initMenu()
    {
       View::share('userinfo', (object) ['id' => Auth::User()->id, 'email' => Auth::User()->email]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is initMenu() in the same class? Because your example suggests it is not in the BaseAdminController

Comment: @jeroenF sorry, now correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via middleware because you can't access the session or authenticated user in the controller's constructor, since the middlware isn't runnig yet:

```
class BaseAdminController extends Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

            $this->initMenu();

            return $next($request);
        });
    }

    private function initMenu()
    {
       View::share('userinfo', (object) ['id' => Auth::User()->id, 'email' => Auth::User()->email]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the view helper function to share stuff easily. Maybe this will help you:

```
view()->share('userinfo', [...data to pass in an array...]);
```

or

```
view()->share('user', Auth::user());
```

This is an example! Only pas the info you want to the view, like you did in your example. But just pass the array, not casting it to object, etc....